# How to find the slicing area in STL-Model

Tags: c++, cad

I've implemented the following code to search and find the vertices on the cross section of a STL-Model. As the models I use contains normally over million nodes(Vertices), it wouldn't be effecient if I really search all the nodes (vertices) and check if they are in the cross section area. So as soon as the first nodes is found I just check the neighbour nodes to find the next edge node. And continue that to reach the first node I have found.

I want to make a list of all the blude vertices on the cropping section of the model:[image]

```
void findCroppingPoints()
{
unsigned int i, f;
int iFirst, k, kOld, p, cnt= 0;
bool isEdge1, isEdge2, isEdge3;

for (i = 0; i < (m_FacetList.size()); i++)
{
    isEdge1 = isEdge2 = isEdge3 = false;

//check the three edges of the triange i to see if they are on the cross-section.
    isEdge1 = isEdgeVertex(i, 1); 
    isEdge2 = isEdgeVertex(i, 2);
    isEdge3 = isEdgeVertex(i, 3);

    if (isEdge1 || isEdge2 || isEdge3)
    {
        iFirst = i;
        saveFacet:
        if (cnt == 0)
            if (isEdge1 = true)
                p = 0;
            else if (isEdge2 = true)
                p = 1;
            else
                p = 2;
        m_EdgePointList.push_back(m_FacetList[i]->vertex[p]);
            cnt++;

        for (f = 0; f < m_FacetList.size(); f++)
        {
            isEdge1 = isEdge2 = isEdge3 = false;
            if (f != iFirst)
                for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    if (m_FacetList[i]->vertex[p] == m_FacetList[f]->vertex[k]) // Search for the triangle, whiche contains the p (the edge, which has found before)
                    {
                        switch (k) // check, which of the two connected edges on this point is on the cross-section
                        {
                        case 0:
                            if (i != f || kOld != 1)
                                if (isEdgeVertex(f, 1))
                                {
                                    isEdge1 = true;
                                    p = 1;
                                    kOld = k;
                                    i = f; // Spring to the new-found triangle
                                    goto saveFacet;
                                }
                            if (i != f || kOld != 2)
                                if (isEdgeVertex(f, 3))
                                {
                                    isEdge3 = true;
                                    p = 2;
                                    kOld = k;
                                    i = f; // Spring to the new-found triangle
                                    goto saveFacet;
                                }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            if (i != f || kOld != 0)
                                if (isEdgeVertex(f, 1))
                                {
                                    isEdge1 = true;
                                    p = 0;
                                    kOld = k;
                                    i = f; // Spring to the new-found triangle
                                    goto saveFacet;
                                }
                            if (i != f || kOld != 2)
                                if (isEdgeVertex(f, 2))
                                {
                                    isEdge2 = true;
                                    p = 2;
                                    kOld = k;
                                    i = f; // Spring to the new-found triangle
                                    goto saveFacet;
                                }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (i != f || kOld != 1)
                                if (isEdgeVertex(f, 2))
                                {
                                    isEdge2 = true;
                                    p = 1;
                                    kOld = k;
                                    i = f; // Spring to the new-found triangle
                                    goto saveFacet;
                                }
                            if (i != f || kOld != 0)
                                if (isEdgeVertex(f, 3))
                                {
                                    isEdge3 = true;
                                    p = 0;
                                    kOld = k;
                                    i = f; // Spring to the new-found triangle
                                    goto saveFacet;
                                }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        break;
    }
}
}
```

This is how I check if an edge of a triangle represent a cross-section edge:

```
bool CSTLModel::isEdgeVertex(unsigned int FacetNum, int VertexNum)
{
bool isEdge;
unsigned int f1, f2, f3;
int k1, k2, p1, p2;

switch (VertexNum)
{
case 1:
    p1 = 0;
    p2 = 1;
    break;
case 2:
    p1 = 1;
    p2 = 2;
    break;
case 3:
    p1 = 2;
    p2 = 0;
    break;
}
for (f1 = 0 ; f1 < m_FacetList.size(); f1++)
    {
        if (f1 != FacetNum)
        {
            isEdge = true;
            for (k1 = 0; k1 < 3; k1++)
                if (m_FacetList[FacetNum]->vertex[p1] == m_FacetList[f1]->vertex[k1])
                    for (k2 = 0; k2 < 3; k2++)
                        if (m_FacetList[FacetNum]->vertex[p2] == m_FacetList[f1]->vertex[k2])
                        {
                            isEdge = false;
                            goto endLoop;
                        }
        }
    }
endLoop:
return isEdge;
}
```

But that doesn't work if there are more than one cropping section on the model, I can't jump to the next section, without having to search in all the nodes.

Do you know any other simpler algorithm to find the cropping sections in STL Model? Or any solution to the problem in above?

Comment: That is a 3D-Model. the triangles are in space. So each vertix is represented by a coordinate of x, y and z in the space.

Comment: First of all you need to generate the list of border faces. And it is obvious that there are no way to avoid checking of this property for all faces if we don't have any information about the number of cropping sections. So, you need to do these checks as efficient as it is possible, since there are so many faces. And after it you will just check vertices of the faces from this list.

Answer (score 0):

I found The the answer using the class map of stl (St. Lib.). So I could save all the Bases of the model in as a vector o coordinates and then as a single "key" of the map and the Vertices on each Base as Value coupled with the key:

```
    findCroppingPoints()
{
    long int oldMapSize = 0;
    unsigned char p1, p2;
    std::map<std::vector<double>, Coordinate<double>> baseMap;
    std::vector<double> baseVector;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_FacetList.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned char j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
        {
            switch (j) 
            {
            case 0:
                p1 = 0;
                p2 = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                p1 = 0;
                p2 = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                p1 = 1;
                p2 = 0;
                break;
            case 3:
                p1 = 1;
                p2 = 2;
                break;
            case 4:
                p1 = 2;
                p2 = 0;
                break;
            case 5:
                p1 = 2;
                p2 = 1;
                break;
            default:
                throw ErrorObj("Unknown_flag.");
            }
            baseVector.push_back(m_FacetList[i]->vertex[p1].x());
            baseVector.push_back(m_FacetList[i]->vertex[p1].y());
            baseVector.push_back(m_FacetList[i]->vertex[p1].z());
            baseVector.push_back(m_FacetList[i]->vertex[p2].x());
            baseVector.push_back(m_FacetList[i]->vertex[p2].y());
            baseVector.push_back(m_FacetList[i]->vertex[p2].z());
```

Whenever the size of the map is not changed, that means the last key (vector) exist already and is therefore no edge base

```
oldMapSize = baseMap.size();
                baseMap[baseVector] = m_FacetList[i]->vertex[p1];
                if (oldMapSize == baseMap.size())
                {
                    baseMap.erase(baseVector);
                }
                baseVector.clear();
            }
        }
        std::map<std::vector<double>, Coordinate<double>>::iterator it = baseMap.begin();
        while (it != baseMap.end())
        {
            m_EdgePointList.push_back(it->second);
            ++it;
        }
        baseMap.clear();
    }
```

Just like that I could find all the edge bases without having to check this Property(being edge Base) for every single base.